# PHP - Inserting multiple rows from multiple CSV files having consistent columns in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Multiple CSV files have consistent 26 column headers. I am using plain PHP to insert the data in MySQL. Data may contain > 100k rows.

Here is my sample CSV file.

[image: Here is my csv file]

Following is my code:

```
while(($line = fgetcsv($csvFile)) !== FALSE){
    //to get the data from csv
    $account_code = $line[0];
    $caller_number = $line[1];
    $callee_number = $line[2];
  .
  .
  .

    $action_type=$line[23];
    $source_trunk_name=$line[24];
    $dest_trunk_name =$line[25];

    $query = $db->query("INSERT INTO `cdrnew`
                (`account_code`, `caller_number`, `callee_number`, ...........,`action_type`, `source_trunk_name`, `dest_trunk_name`)
            VALUES ('".$account_code."','".$caller_number."', '".$callee_number."', ............,'".$action_type."','".$source_trunk_name."','".$dest_trunk_name."')");
```

Is this the right approach to insert the data from CSV to MySQL if I have consistent 26 column headers across all the CSV files. Or is there a better approach?

Comment: No and for a number of reasons not least of which is Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

Comment: Using a parameterised, prepared and then bound query would allow you to compile the query only once but execute it lakh times

Comment: Is there a specific problem with the code you have?

Comment: No. data is getting inserted in mysql with this code. But I doubt whether should I follow this approach. Or can we use bulk insert or anything else for better performance ?

Comment: Which database extension are you using, `MySQLI` or `PDO`?

Comment: I am using `Mysqli` database extension

Comment: From what I recall bulk insert is faster then iterating over each row 1 by 1.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a parameterised and bound query. The benefit above and beyond the obvious, of removing the possibility of [SQL Injections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php), would be that you can compile the query once but run it many times with new parameters each time.
This stops the database having to do 1000's of query compilations and therefore 1000 of unnecessary round trips to the server and back.

First move the query outside the loop and prepare it there

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `cdrnew`
                (`account_code`, `caller_number`, `callee_number`, 
                .,.,.,.,.,.,
                `action_type`, `source_trunk_name`, `dest_trunk_name`)
            VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

while(($line = fgetcsv($csvFile)) !== FALSE){

    $stmt->bind_param('ssssssssssssssssssssssssss',
                        $line[0], $line[1], $line[2], $line[3], $line[4],
                        $line[5], $line[6], $line[7], $line[8], $line[9],
                        $line[10], $line[11], $line[12], $line[13], $line[14],
                        $line[15], $line[16], $line[17], $line[18], $line[19],
                        $line[20], $line[21], $line[22], $line[23], $line[24],
                        $line[25]
        );
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

> NOTE: You may want to add some error checking to this base layout